# Create Devise User From A Different Form and Controller - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

We have two models, a 'Devise User' and an 'Influencer'. An Influencer is a User, as such it must have a User (from the db standpoint). A User can be multiple other things. Thus, we want to have the ability to sign up a User without being an Influencer and we want to sign up a User when they want to sign up as an Influencer.

I have a form like so:

`influencers/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @influencer do |i| %>
  <%= i.fields_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |u| %>
    <div id="registration_fields">
      <%= render 'devise/registrations/registration_fields', f: u %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class='field'>
  <%= i.label :twitter_handle %><br/>
  <%= i.text_field :twitter_handle %>
</div>

<div class='field'>
  <%= i.label :short_bio %><br/>
  <%= i.text_area :short_bio %>
</div>
```

`/views/devise/registrations/_registration_fields`

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :first_name %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name %> <br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>
```

We've modified the ApplicationHelper and 'new' method so that it could render this Devise form without problems. Unfortunately, we are stuck as to how to properly make the 'create' method for our InfluencersController.

This is the hash we receive:

```
Parameters: {..., "influencer"=>{"user"=>{"first_name"=>"buddy", "last_name"=>"king", "email"=>"bdking@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "twitter_handle"=>"@bdking", "short_bio"=>"None"}, "commit"=>"Join as influencer"
```

Essentially we want to Devise to handle the user information while we handle the influencer information. We have tried calling the Devise::RegistrationsController.new.create method from within InfluencersController#create. However, this poses its own difficulties (even with multiple hacks we reach different problems such as, missing '@response' or missing 'response.env' or missing 'devise.mappings').

With that said, We believe that inheriting will allow us to call 'super' in the create function. However, we do not want to have InfluencersController inherit from Devise::RegistrationsController since this controller is not by any means a true Devise controller.

Is there any way we could get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the tried and true pattern of `users` and `roles`.

Basically your `User` class is in charge of authentication (identity) and the user has many `Roles` which can be used for authorization (permissions).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles

  def has_role?(role)
    roles.where(name: role)
  end
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id
end
```

So an "influencer" is really just a user with a Role(name: "influencer")  attached to it. The real power and flexibility is that it makes it trivial to implement granting/revoking roles from a web GUI.

And you don't have to mess around with how Devise/Warden handle authentication to support multiple classes which can get really messy.

Best part is that the [Rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) makes it really trivial to set up.

If you need to setup a specific endpoint (`influences/registrations`) to register "influencers" you can simply override the build_resource method in the Devise controller:

```
class InfluencerRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def resource_class
    User
  end

  def build_resource
    super
    self.resource.roles.new(name: :influencer)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you absolutely have to you could use STI or MTI. But the cons are pretty huge in terms of complexity and performance.

Comment: What is STI or MTI? And you are right, we are using User roles where one of them is an influencer. However, since influencers have extra data members, we make them their own table. I am asking if there is a way to have the InfluencersController register a User without it inheriting from a Devise::RegistrationsController.

Comment: Single Table Inheritance and Multiple Table Inheritance. Yes, you can create a controller from scratch that registers users - its not that much different from any other CRUD controller except that you call `sign_in @user` to get Warden to store the id in the session before redirecting.